# Eventos SQL. ¿Cómo crear evento para restar un número 1 diario por 7 días, y al llegar a 0 elimine un contenido de la fila en la tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo una tabla con un campo int con el dato 7 como número de días,
mi objetivo es crear un evento que cada media noche revise las cuentas en el campo de los 7 días, y les reste un día si el valor actual no es igual a 1.
Pero si es igual, entonces realiza la segunda parte del proceso, modificar el contenido. Todos los días:

Con algo de código mostraré detalles sobre mi objetivo y describiré lo que he intentado:

```
-- Primero activar Programador de eventos
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

-- Evento SQL #1
CREATE EVENT delete_no_vip_images
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2023-01-01 23:59:00'
    -- o quizá CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

DO 
BEGIN
    -- Trabajo de borrado condicional
    -- Necesito definir la condición IF
    UPDATE images
    SET
        -- Eliminar imagen
        image=NULL,

        -- Cambiar descripción
        description='No disponible porque cumplió su ciclo semanal.',

        -- Solo para referencia de tiempo
        delete_day=NULL,

        -- Y el de los 7 dias:
        remaining_days=NULL

    -- Porque ya sería el último día
    WHERE remaining_days = 1;
    
    -- Trabajo de ciclo diario
    -- Necesito definir la condición ELSE
    UPDATE images
    SET
        -- Restar 1 a remaining_days
        -- No se como lograr esta sección 
        
        --remaining_days -= 1

    -- o quizá de esta forma
--(remaining_days - 1) AS remaining_days
        
        -- Donde sea mayor que 1
        WHERE remaining_days > 1;
    
    -- y termina por esta vez
    END;
```

Como se puede notar, me falta bastante conocimiento sobre eventos SQL. He intentado correr el evento en phpMyAdmin pero no está bien formado el código.

Quiero poder hacerlo directamente en la base de datos, porque si lo hago en PHP entonces tendría que añadirlo a cada entrada de clientes, porque PHP no trabaja independiente.
¿Que otro punto de vista estoy olvidando?
¿Alguna otra idea o método?
Gracias por leer.

**Actualización**

He mejorado mi código y ya funciona, incluyendo el consejo de la respuesta que acepto.

```
CREATE EVENT test_delete_no_vip_images
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2023-01-01 00:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    COMMENT 'Evento diario. Actualizar tabla y eliminar datos cumplido 7 días.'
    DO

BEGIN
    -- Primero, trabajo de ciclo diario
    UPDATE images
    
    -- Aceptado!
    -- Restar 1 día a remaining_days
    SET remaining_days = remaining_days - 1
    
    -- Donde sea mayor que 0
    WHERE remaining_days > 0;
    
    
    -- Segundo, trabajo de borrado condicional
    UPDATE images
    
    
    SET
    
    -- Eliminar imagen
    image=NULL,
    
    -- Cambiar descripción
    description='No disponible porque cumplió su ciclo semanal.',
    
    -- Limpiar referencia de tiempo
    delete_day=NULL,
    
    -- Y el de los 7 días colocar a NULL
    remaining_days=NULL
    
    -- Porque ya es el final del último día (0)
    WHERE remaining_days = 0;

-- y termina por esta vez
END;
```

Otro detalle: que finalmente lo logré por la pestaña Eventos de phpMyAdmin, después de seleccionar la base de datos, **pero fuera de cualquier tabla**. Por la pestaña SQL, no estoy seguro que funcione, pero no importa no es imprescindible.

Y para comparar el tiempo, también se puede [usar:](https://donnierock.com/2013/01/30/eventos-en-mysql-planificar-tareas-fecha/)
WHERE DATE_ADD( uploaded, INTERVAL 7 DAY) < NOW();

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces que se ejecute un día de la semana en específico?

Comment: Buenos días @Luis Cazares, el asunto es que cada usuario con cuenta gratis publica sus productos a vender, y en los acuerdos del sitio he establecido que se mantiene por una semana. Las subidas son en diferentes momentos de la semana y es mi deber cumplir con el tiempo establecido **de cada imagen**, por eso es el control diario a medida noche. Hace un momento [encontré](https://donnierock.com/2013/01/30/eventos-en-mysql-planificar-tareas-fecha/) lo siguiente: `WHERE DATE_ADD( uploaded, INTERVAL 7 DAY) < NOW() and remaining_days =1;` y puede servir.

Comment: @Luis Cazares lo otro que creo me está dando problemas es, que quizás estoy tratando de activarlo mediante phpMyAdmin por la vía incorrecta **pestaña SQL**, o que esté desactualizado y por eso no entiende consulta doble.

Comment: ¿Usas la [interfaz gráfica de phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOCyf.png) para eventos?, de lo contrario deberías observar el [delimitador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfb8q.png).

Comment: Correcto @Sal, phpMyAdmin, y ya resolví el problema, pero también visitaré tu enlace sobre delimitador. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está en el segundo `UPDATE` que debería ser:

```
UPDATE images
  SET remaining_days = remaining_days - 1
  WHERE remaining_days > 1;
```

Los formatos:

- `remaining_days -= 1` es más propio de programación y
- `(remaining_days - 1) AS remaining_days` es la sintaxis de las consultas

Prueba y me confirmas qué tal. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Realizando pruebas: como indiqué; estoy tratando de activar el evento desde phpMyAdmin, pestaña SQL, y lo primero que me indica es: Tipo de declaración desconocida. (cerca de END) Aparte de eso al ejecutar, en `WHERE remaining_days = 1;` me indica #1064 error SQL syntax que sólo se arregla eliminando el _;_ entonces me indica otro error en `UPDATE images`, parece que no entiende el tipo de declaración porque todo el tiempo indica error de sintaxis. Quizás sea necesario realizar la consulta de activación desde PHP, a ver si sale bien, no sea que sea error de phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Otra duda que tengo es, que estoy tomando  `remaining_days` como referencia, y está no es clave primaria, no sé si es obligatorio hacer el WHERE con una clave primaria; como el caso de `id`, pero eso no me serviría porque remaining_days es el que actúa como referencia y control, no sé si me explico bien. Se puede llamar sin usar una clave primaria?

Comment: Actualizada mi pregunta para explicar el resultado, porque ya funciona gracias por su trabajo. Aceptada!

Comment: Las expresiones que utilizas en el `WHERE` son simples condiciones booleanas, no tienen nada que ver con claves primarias. Por lo tanto, no existe ninguna obligatoriedad al respecto. Me alegra que la respuesta te haya resultado útil.

Comment: Gracias por los datos extra. Se ve que es tu especialidad las consultas y autorización. Tengo otra publicación relacionada al tema pero con diferente desarrollo. Por favor [revisala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/589935/es-posible-realizar-en-misma-tabla-una-consulta-select-con-dos-subconsultas-upd) cuando puedas si lo deseas.