# ¿Es posible realizar en misma tabla una consulta SELECT con dos subconsultas UPDATE mas SELECT; con objetivo de obtener resultados luego del cambio?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Entiendo que suene como un enredo, y normalmente lo que más se ha buscado es **Hacer UPDATE con los resultados de un SELECT en misma consulta**, he estado buscando en Google y es lo que encuentro.

Pero no es lo que busco. No domino lo suficiente la sintaxis de SQL, pero según lo que entiendo (y usando algo de lógica) reuní y diseñé dos plantillas para que alguien me indique la sintaxis correcta según lo que tengo.

**SQL:**

**Plantilla A**

```
SELECT *
    FROM
(
    UPDATE images_t 
        SET campo1 = 'A', campo2 = 'A'
    WHERE is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days > 0
) AS afectadas_1,

(
    UPDATE images_t 
        SET campo1 = 'B', campo2 = 'B'
    WHERE is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days = 0
) AS afectadas_2,

(
    SELECT *
        FROM images_t
    WHERE is_vip = 'No'
) AS obtenidas 

ORDER BY afectadas_1, afectadas_2, obtenidas;
```

**Plantilla B**

```
SELECT *
    FROM
(
    UPDATE images_t 
    
    -- Primera consulta
    IF is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days > 0
    THEN SET 
            campo1 = 'A',   campo2 = 'A'
        
    -- Segunda consulta
    IF is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days = 0
    THEN SET
        campo1 = 'B',   campo2 = 'B'
) AS afectadas,

(
    SELECT *
        FROM images_t
    WHERE is_vip = 'No'
) AS obtenidas 

ORDER BY afectadas, obtenidas;
```

Algo así necesito, de lo contrario tendré que realizar dos o tres consultas a BD cada vez.

Por si se necesita; aquí mi CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images_t (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_vip` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `campo1` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `campo2` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `remaining_days` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Regresivo',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Saludos al maestro @David JP que me ayudó anteriormente con algo parecido en otra pregunta.

**Datos de ejemplo:**

Es parecido a lo que se logra en mi [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/589748/250504)
pero en este caso, manualmente y para recibir registros en JSON al llamar a esa API.
La URL de ejemplo sería: `https://ejemplo.com/api/?show=true` y recibo datos actualizados.
Pero si se llama sin ?show=true por ejemplo mediante un BOT; *también se actualizan los datos*;
**pero no se recibe en el JSON**.

**Tabla: images_t**

**id= 1,**

**is_vip = 'No',**

**campo1='Cualquier cadena aquí',**

**campo2 = 'Otra cadena aquí',**

**remaining_days = 6**

Esa no es realmente la tabla que utilizo; es solo para simplificar
la tabla es la misma que en la pregunta que cité arriba.
Mi PHP sería más o menos así:

**PHP**

```
$response = [];

// Comprobar si hay identificador de muestra (show)
$show = $_GET['show'];

// Si no es GET es POST [cualquiera me sirve]
if($show == NULL)$show = $_POST['show'];

// Comprobar el horario ( < 00:30:00 UTC)
// y la variable show
$time_now = date("H:i:s") < '00:30:00'; //true o false

// Es BOT   o es    show
if( $time_now || isset($show) ) {
    
    // Obtener la conexión a la base de datos
    require('../global/php/conexion.php');
    
    // Conexión
    try {
        
        // Comprobar si es el horario correcto para ejecutar
        if( $time_now ) {
            
            // Modificar contenido de la base de datos
            $query =
                // Usaré el ejemplo más corto, el primero.
                "SELECT *"  // Esto con objetivo de obtener todo
                    ."FROM
                    (
                        UPDATE images_t "
                            
                            // Primero, se cambian los campos ...
                            ."SET campo1 = 'A', campo2 = 'A' "
                        
                        // Si cumple con:
                        ."WHERE is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days > 0
                    ) AS afectadas_1," // Espero que en 'afectadas_1' se guarde eso mismo (opcional)
                    
                ."(
                        UPDATE images_t "
                            
                            // Lo mismo anterior ...
                            ."SET campo1 = 'B', campo2 = 'B' "
                        
                        // Pero con otra condición:
                        ."WHERE is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days = 0
                    ) AS afectadas_2";
            
            // Terminan los UPDATEs
        }// if time_now
        
        // Comprobar nuevamente si hay variable 'show' para añadir subsolicitud SELECT
        if( isset($show) ) {
            
            $query .= ",
                (
                    SELECT `id`, `is_vip`, `campo1`, `campo2`, `remaining_days`
                    FROM `images_t`"
                    
                    // Obteniendo sólo los campos que tengan ...
                    ."WHERE is_vip = 'No'
                ); ";
        }
        
        // Ejecutar
        $statement = $pdo->prepare( $query );
        $executed = $statement->execute();
        
    }catch( PDOException $pdoE ) {
        // Mostrar error si lo hubiera
        $response += ["ok" => false, "error" => "Error de conexión: ".$pdoE->getMessage()];
    }
}
```

No es necesario incluir cómo proceso los datos.
Si se necesita más aclaraciones, por favor indicarme. Gracias.

Comment: Introduce unos datos de ejemplo y muéstranos, con pasos intermedios, el resultado que esperas para esos datos de muestra. Con un ejemplo todo se entiende mucho más rápido...

Comment: Listo @David JP, ve ahora si logro explicar bien.

Comment: Para empezar te recomiendo usar `JOIN` entre tablas en vez de `FROM` a subconsultas. Recuerda que, por defecto, se realizará una unión cruzada de los resultados de todas las subconsultas. Es decir, que si tienes dos subconsultas y una da 10 resultados y la otra 20, tendrás 200 resultados en total. Si tienes 10, 20 y 5 en la tercera subconsulta, tendrás 1000 resultados. Además, todo será atómico y no podrás acceder a los valores tras la modificación del `UPDATE` en una misma consulta (por poner un ejemplo). Deberías separarlo en dos pasos: 1º modificar y luego obtener los datos actualizados.

Comment: pregunta, si ya haces el update, para que quieres hacerlo de nuevo?, que tal si ejecutas el update y guardas el numero de registros aparte y luego lo muestras con los respectivos joins

Comment: @OscarGarcia entonces lo que necesito es conocer la estructura del código para generar una consulta UPDATE, que me actualice la tabla bajo dos condiciones diferentes; ejecutando la acción según cada condición. Y luego, en ese mismo query obtener los campos modificados ...

Comment: Continuación: y @JackNavaRow ahí es donde entraría el JOIN, es así? ¿Cómo se debe hacer?

Comment: Es importante entender que una base de datos es un conjunto de información alojada en unas tablas que, tras los `UPDATE` que sean necesarios, va a ser modificada. Necesitamos ver el antes y el después del contenido de esas tablas para poder ayudarte. Ahora mismo estás demasiado preocupado por el "cómo hacerlo" pero debes centrarte en el "qué hacer", que para tí es trivial, pero los demás debemos entender para poder ayudarte con el "cómo".

Comment: @DavidJP es que hasta me es difícil explicarlo. La idea es "simplificando todo", realizar una llamada a una dirección web, que su cometido es comprobar y/o cambiar datos así: Primero busca donde están los `is_vip='No'` y que `remaining_days > 0` para (A) cambiarlo restando `-1` (B otra y así, etc) pudiera ser con un SELECT primero. Seguidamente se comprueba otra vez `is_vip='No'` pero ahora donde `remaining_days` ya sea `= 0` pero no por la acción anterior; sino de otro día pasado, para cambiar ese dato `remaining_days` a `=NULL`. Espero poder aclarar todo ahora.

Comment: ¿No tenías un evento que te hacía ese trabajo? ¿Para qué lo vinculas ahora a una URL? Para simplificarlo tendrás que separar las cosas, no juntarlas, ¿no? ¿Qué hay de malo en dar varios pasos para conseguir algo? ¿Para qué quieres hacerlo en un único paso?

Comment: @DavidJP donde tengo alojada mi web, como por el momento es gratis awardspace.com no me permiten SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; por los permisos en la BD. entonces usaré un BOT en otro sitio, que llame a esa dirección. No se cómo hacerlo en una sola consulta, y que opcionalmente si la llamo con un parámetro show, obtengo una lista en JSON. Necesito entender la estructura de como se hace.

Comment: Almenos ayudenme con una consulta para PHP que haga los UPDATE. Creo que no puede ser una consulta tipo: `UPDATE images_t SET campo1 = 'A' WHERE is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days > 0 OR SET campo1 = 'B' WHERE is_vip = 'No' AND remaining_days = 0` eso no funciona, ¿o si?

Comment: La consulta es la misma que tienes en el evento, busca en tu hosting cómo configurar `cron_jobs` y lo tendrás resuelto...